# Show Geometric Network Topology data in the web

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, geometric-network, html5, smallworld-gis

I am trying to locate any API's for JavaScript (or other) that will help me to display current linear Geometric Network Topology and add multiple point/line geometry from JSON in HTML/JS. I specifically need to have my users perform typical tools like trace route and analysis in web interface on this linear network. I am just trying to find out if there is a JS or other Web API to handle these types of requests?

Comment: Would you consider using GP services for that? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Geometric_Network_Trace/0154000005s0000000/

Comment: my client wants an open source solution. I have already looked into the infrastructure editing tools for ArcGIS Server. Any other toolkits or ideas? I am under the assumption to do this I will need a customized programming solution to accomplish. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you're using smallworld (tag `smallworld`), GSS is usually used to provide an API over http. Note that this isn't an open source solution.